# Swift Firebase logout issue, only successfully logout after reopen the app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello guys I have a really strange issue on my ios app. For example, I am now on "Test1" user profile page, after I click logout button, my app will successfully logout through firebase, but if I login again with a new account called "Test2", after logging in the profile page will still be "Test 1"'s profile page. However, If now I kill the app, and reopen it, profile page will fetch all "Test2" profile information. Can Anyone tell me what might be the problem? Thank you very much. Heres are my logout code and login code.

```
func handleLogOut(){
    do{
       try Auth.auth().signOut();
     } catch let logoutError {
       print(logoutError)
     }
}


func login(){
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passTextField.text else{
          return
    }  
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in 
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        error
    }
    })
}
```

Comment: After logout check Auth.auth().currentUser.uid is that of "Test1" or "Test2"?

Answer (score 1):

When app become active please keep the check.

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  // User is signed in.
  // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // ...
}
```

I am sure there you will get user is logout. So navigate to login page or screen as per your app requirement. Modifycyour code as below make currentUser = nil in logout and give value at time of login.

```
func handleLogOut(){
    do{
       try Auth.auth().signOut();
       currentUser = nil
     } catch let logoutError {
       print(logoutError)
     }
}


func login(){
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passTextField.text else{
          return
    }  
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in 
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        error
    } else {
        currentUser = user
    }

    })
}
```

Comment: Hello, I already have this, what happen is that. When app is started, it will go to "VC1", if user is not signed in, this VC will dismiss and go to Login Page. The reason it is strange is that, after I log out, i will go back to login page, but when I login with a new user, the date or user info wont refresh or updated, i have to kill the app then reopen it, and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Where are you storing userinfo? is it database or user default preference?.

Comment: So here is the issue I can think of. So what I did is that lets say i have 2 VC, login VC is on the top of main VC. So everytime I open the app, I will use the function that you posted, if the currenderUser == nil, the LoginVC will poping up. Then on Login VC when I input a new user info and login back, it will navigates me on the main VC, and stay there but the actual user info did not fetch from firebase server. The login logout method 100% works, because after I kill the app and reopen it, the new user info will be updated.

Comment: So you need to make currenderUser property nil when you logout for user. I think that will resolve your issue.

Comment: Add give value for currenderUser when you signup and login user.